# Help with ternary operator

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't think I am using the ternary operator correctly as I am not getting the results am I after:

```
buildHTML.push("<a href='http://mysite/user?screen_name=" + data.friend == null ? data.user.me : data.friend + "'>" + data.friend == null ? data.user.me : data.friend + "</a>");
```

This gives me `null` if `friend` is `null`, and gives me `friend` if `friend` is `not null`

It should be giving me `me` if `friend` is `null` and `friend` if `friend` is `not null`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you doing it twice? Store it into a variable and do the logic check once.

Comment: Ternary operators are extremely low in "order of operations" priority.  You almost always need to wrap them in parentheses when combining with other operators like +

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap up the ternary logic:

```
buildHTML.push("<a href='http://mysite/user?screen_name=" + (data.friend == null ? data.user.me : data.friend) + "'>" + (data.friend == null ? data.user.me : data.friend) + "</a>");
```

You may also need to check to see whether `data.friend` is == or === to `null`.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding some parentheses:

```
buildHTML.push("<a href='http://mysite/user?screen_name=" + 
(data.friend == null ? data.user.me : data.friend)
 + "'>" + 
(data.friend == null ? data.user.me : data.friend)
+ "</a>");
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things to note that may help you out:

- Use === instead of == when comparing items in JavaScript.
- data.friend may be undefined, which is different than null, you may want to do a different check.